# Security considerations: can you intercept UIWebView / UIWebViewDelegate

Tags: ios, oauth

From a user perspective can it be a security risk to let an app not leave the application. Like letting the app handle the login view in a UIWebView within the app itself.

Should you not use a Custom URL Scheme in a .plist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do. The more you keep the user in your app, the longer he'll stay and use it.

It's generally a bid idea to use a `UIWebView`, as the user experience is not the same compared to native interface.

Concerning Oauth, even the dialog asking for user credentials and/or approval may be coded, all you need to do is to POST the data at the right URL when the user submit.

If you really want to use a web view, then yes it's better to include it in the app, overall for an authentication.

Comment: I agree, from a user experience - keeping the user in the app is the best. But I am thinking in terms of security from a technical point.